# XtraReport merge cell vertically in devexpress 12.2.7?

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

Is there anyway to merge cell vertically in devexpress 12.2.7 xtratable?

I can do it horizontally by deleting cells but not with vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was [implemented](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S31499) in v2014 vol 1.3.:

> An integer **RowSpan** property has been introduced for the **XRTableCell** class. This property specifies the number of merged cells.

So, in this version you can create a table like this:
[image: Merged column]

In your version the only one way is to create additional tables for each vertically merged cells. There are three tables in this picture:
[image: Several tables]